# Classic ASP cookies removed upon leaving the page or terminating the page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, asp-classic

I need to remove a cookie that has been created in server side. The goal is to remove the cookie when navigating in the other pages or when the browser is terminated/closes.

Any suggestions are welcome. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using the cookie "Path" property.  This should restrict the cookie only to the page you specify.

For example:

```
Response.Cookies("MYCOOKIE") = "SOME_VALUE"
Response.Cookies("MYCOOKIE").Path = "PATH_TO_YOUR_PAGE"
```

By not setting the Expiration property for the cookie, it should be cleared once the user closes the browser.

Comment: It seems to be working. Thanks. However, when I tried to navigate away to the page by changing the URL or closing the current tab of the browser then, the cookie still exists. How can I force this cookie to be removed?